# android - Text editable inside plain text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to do something like this image in my Android app:
[image]

Where the black lines is **plain text** (this text is fixed and user can't edit and remove), and inside this plain text, there are a input or white space where user can add some words to the text (**editable text**).
I don't know how I can do it. Someone can help me or give me a idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is create a relative layout and create the textview which is matchparent. and create your editable textview and place it above the textview , follow like this  ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB B  

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB



        aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB aAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBaAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"/>


    <EditText
        android:background="#23cc6f"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Editable Textview is here"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but this depends on screen size, and this is not valid for me